# How can I change the Hebrew font in cjhebrew?

Tags: fonts, hebrew, texpad

The answer to be found at the [fontspec link](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/) seems to me less than useful. Could you please write a snippet showing how to change the Hebrew (but not the English) font when I use the cjhebrew package?
Your help will be much appreciated. It might be of use to mention that I use Texpad to write Latex under OS X 10.9.4
Thank you
Adrian

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have never used it, but a quick look at the documentation strongly suggests that `cjhebrew` is designed to support the use of the particular fonts included in the package. I think if you wish to use a different font, you need a different package. Or you could use Xe/LuaTeX with `fontspec`. But `fontspec` will not mix well with `cjhebrew`. [I'm not sure what answer you are referring to - that link is just to information on CTAN about `fontspec`.]

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt answer. What I meant was how to change the cjhebrew fonts among themselves. Being a beginner, a snippet would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by changing the 'fonts among themselves'. Please provide an MWE and explain exactly what you want to change in the output.

Comment: I understand that the package cjhebrew comes with about a dozen of fonts of its own. I was wondering how to switch from a cjhebrew font to another cjhebrew font, and maybe you know also a source with a list of all the cjhebrew fonts. I hope my question is now clear enough. Many thanks

Comment: Not really. What makes you think it provides that many fonts? As far as I can tell, it provides 2 fonts. One is used for text at smaller sizes and the other for text at larger sizes. So you'll switch when you are using a different sized font. The [sty file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/hebrew/cjhebrew/cjhebrew.sty) includes the font definitions provided by the package and the [map file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/hebrew/cjhebrew/cjhebrew.map) maps the fonts for TeX.

Comment: Oh. OK. Well, I'm glad that was helpful even if I'm not sure which question I answered!

Answer (score 2):

I would not use cjhebrew, it is old (2004) and you will not see your Hebrew in your source document. Given you are on a Mac, you have full unicode and opentype support. I suggest you use XeTeX/XeLaTeX and an appropriate unicode font. You can then typeset the Hebrew using any font that has the appropriate glyphs. There are a number available. Some of the free fonts have a good range (free serif, Babel Unicode), but I find Cardo has the widest range of anciliary characters and accents. Install the font on  your system as normal and it will be accessible to XeTeX/XeLaTeX.

A MWE is below where the Hebrew is set using a different font from the main text, though that is not necessary if the main font has the appropriate glyphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{FreeSans}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=australian]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}
Genesis 1:1 \texthebrew{בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I just want to note that some users may only need a few Hebrew words or characters in a whole document, and the `cjhebrew` package makes that possible without leaving `pdflatex`.